# Hi i have this header.css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

`I am having issue in react in which my css file is not working properly , so the first header in css file is working fine but (header2) is not working in webpage its not changing , same with every other class i create after header , only header is responsive to Header.css file , please help me solve this issue.`
`Header.js file.`
`i have imported the css file correctly please help`

`const Header = () =>`

`{`
`return`

`(`
`<div className='header'>`

`<div classname="header2">`

<imgsrc="gym.png"alt="" src="gym.png"
`</div>`
`</div>`

`Header.css file`

`.header`
`{`

`display:flex;`

`padding: 15px 20px;`

`justify-content: space-between;`

`position: sticky;`

`background-color: rgb(235, 199, 153);`

`z-index: 100;`

`top:0;`

`box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -9px black rgba(0,0,0,0,752);`

`}`

`.header2>img`

`{`

`height: 10px;`

`}`

`i tried changing names, shifting sequence but only .header would response in my live server`

Comment: What is `<imgsrc`? Did you mean `<img src...`?

Comment: Please format your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is react classname. in react it should be className(UpperCase)

```
<div className="header2">
```